# Unable to move a file using PHP in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php

Hi all this php code is perfectly working on windows 
but i am unable to move a attached file to a folder in ubuntu 
using this code.

```
<?php
$db=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("iphone",$db) or die("Error mysql connection");

$path="event-image/";

$path=$path.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$path))

{

$ename=$_POST['ename'];
$elocation=$_POST['elocation'];
$date=$_POST['edate'];
$stime=$_POST['stime'];
$etime=$_POST['etime'];
$website=$_POST['website'];
$image=basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$sql="insert into event(ename,elocation,date,stime,etime,website,image)

 values('$ename','$elocation','$date','$stime','$etime','$website','$image')";

$result=mysql_query($sql,$db);

}

echo 'Message has been sent<br>';



?>
```

Comment: did your user, most it is www-data, have the rights to write into the new folder?

Comment: Probably because the folder doesn't exist or is missing write permissions - you should check the error log or enable display errors. No error message means it's only possible to guess.

Comment: please add 
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
at beginning of file to see the error

Comment: "i am unable to" is _not_ a helpful description. What does that mean? Do you get an error? Nothing happens? The universe implodes if you try?

Comment: In the future, please remove irrelevant parts from your code, like the DB interaction.

Answer (score 0):

#### On File Permissions in Linux

In Linux web server process is used to run as different user as used for logging in and uploading/storing files. You need to check what user your web server is running as. After that you need to check if *that user* is permitted to write files into selected target folder.

Using this command on server will show user name installed web server is running as (requiring privileged access):

```
$ sudo ps aux | awk '$11 ~ /apache|lighttpd|nginx|cherokee/ {print $1}' | grep -v root | uniq
```

After that you might check if target folder is writable by that user (mostly, it's `www-data`).
:

```
$ sudo -u www-data /bin/touch -- /path/to/your/file
```

If this prints "Permission denied" you need to fix permissions on containing folders. This implies the selected target folder and all its parents for the latter might prevent web server from even reading subfolders web server is actually permitted to write into. See this example:

1. `/var` is world-readable and world-executable (or world-enterable on folders).
2. `/var/www` is world-readbale and world-enterable.
3. `/var/www/private` is owner-enterable only and not owned by your web server.
4. `/var/www/private/target` is your target folder made web server writable before.

In this scenario web server won't be permitted to write in `/var/www/private/target` for it's not even permitted to enter that one's parent folder `/var/www/private`.

**But don't use `chmod 0777 /pathname` just because it's the easiest to do!**

Basically I'm used to have my existing folders owned by my login user, but group set to group of web server. If you have folders web server is designed to store files in, you could simply grant write privilege to group on that single folder.

```
$ chown myuser:www-data /var/www
$ find /var/www -type d | xargs chmod 0750
$ find /var/www '!' -type d | xargs chmod 0640
$ chmod g+w /var/www/upload
```

Note:

1. In first command, `www-data` isn't name of a user, but name of a group. It's usually same as web server's user name, but it might differ in your case.
2. `/var/www` is used as example here and should point to your application's root folder. Subfolder `upload` is yet another example for subfolder web server might write files into.

#### How to select target folders in PHP

According to your code the target folder is given relatively. In that case you won't find the folder all this checking has to be done in for you don't know what folder your target folder is actually related to. You might try binding your relative target folder's name to the folder your PHP script resides in using some code like this:

```
$path = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/event-image/';
```

or

```
$path = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../upload/event-image/';
```

It depends on your application's folder layout. But this way you are using some absolute pathname for moving file and it's still working in different contexts or on different servers.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: You're right ... hasn't been an answer. What about might edited approach?

Comment: What about trying to find out first what the actual problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be because Apache needs permission on those files ?
What are the file permissions set to and what is the owner of the files ?

Try giving them some more permissions by doing something like:

```
chmod -R 777 /dir/that/has/files
```

Or give them sufficient permissions and then make apache the ower:

```
chmod -R 655 /dir/that/has/files
chown httpd:httpd /dir/that/has/files
```

I'm no PHP developer so i couldn't verify your code even if i wanted.

Comment: This is not an "answer", it is a wild guess. This should have been a comment.

Comment: I get that, i don't have the reputation to add comments to the original question. That's why i posted it like this. Atleast it provides information and hopefully a resolution.

Comment: As long as it is unclear what the actual problem is (the OP has not provided enough information by far) it makes no sense to try to send guesses as answers. If you cannot write a comment yet then is your hint really _that_ important to post it as a pseudo answer? Others already pointed out the possibility that this might be a server side permission problem. What if it turns out the problem is something completely different? Then this is one more question on SO with "answers" that have nothing to do with the question. This is called "spamming".